# Two table view in one view controller - pushing any view controller is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview

I have two table view in one view controller.

They works great! But they are not pushing to any vc.

Under -(void) viewDidLoad method in my main view controller:

```
horizontalViewController = [[HorizontalViewController alloc] init];

verticalViewController = [[VerticalViewController alloc] init];


[horizontalTableView setDataSource:horizontalViewController];

[verticalTableView setDataSource:verticalViewController];


[horizontalTableView setDelegate:horizontalViewController];

[verticalTableView setDelegate:verticalViewController];


horizontalViewController.view = horizontalViewController.tableView;

verticalViewController.view = verticalViewController.tableView;
```

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: In my think your question is too ambiguous. What exactly is problem? more explain please?

Comment: This sample project guide me about adding two table views to one view controller: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews
didSelectRow.. method works fine but I can't push any view controller when I tap any cell in the table view.

Comment: I'm looking at it now your sample code project. where is your pushViewController code??? you say pushing, what's the mean? In Generally pushing mean is following code. [[self navigationController] pushViewController:yourViewController]];

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    NSLog(@"tapped");
    
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    VerticalDetailViewController *verticalDetail = [[VerticalDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerticalDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:verticalDetail animated:YES];

}

It's not working.

Comment: Make sure self.navigationController is not null

Comment: It is not null..
I tried to [self.view addSubview:..]; but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

refer a following code. If you want use a pushViewController method. 
You must be have a NavigationViewController.
so, your structure is a little complex. one ViewController has number of Two TableViewController. one ViewController is not have NavigationController. NavigaitonViewController necessarily belong to the app when it runs because it should be configured.

**TwoTableViewsAppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UINavigationController *naviController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];
    [window setRootViewController:naviController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**TwoTableViewsViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    if (firstController == nil) {
        firstController = [[FirstTVContoller alloc] init];
    }
    if (secondController == nil) {
        secondController = [[SecondTVController alloc] init];
    }

    [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
    [secondTable setDataSource:secondController];

    [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
    [secondTable setDelegate:secondController];

    firstController.view = firstController.tableView;
    secondController.view = secondController.tableView;

    firstController.rootViewController = self;
    secondController.rootViewController = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**FirstTVContoller.h , SecondTVController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FirstTVContoller : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

**FirstTVContoller.m , SecondTVController.m**

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    VerticalDetailViewController *verticalDetailViewController = [[VerticalDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerticalDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self.rootViewController navigationController] pushViewController:verticalDetailViewController animated:YES];

}
```